# unable to import module in same directory when using pytest

Tags: python, pytest, python-import

I am having a problem running pytest in a situation when my app calls another script in the same directory. Here is my directory structure:

```
├── my_project/
│   ├── application/
│   |   ├──__init__.py
│   |   ├──app.py
│   |   ├──utils.py   
│   ├── application_test/
│   |   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── unit_test.py
```

The code in `app.py` has the statement: `from utils import func1, func2, func3` and this works fine when I run `$ python app.py`. However, when I run `$ py.test` from the `my_project` directory level, I get the error "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'utils'." The errors comes from this line in `unit_test.py`:

```
import application.app
```

Because that line triggers `app.py` which then tries to import from `utils.py` and somehow `app.py` does not see the `utils.py` file even though it is in the same directory.

I have tried using `$ python -m pytest application_test`, as well as having `__init__.py` in the root and without, but none of these or other answers on stackoverflow seem to work.

Comment: try `my_project.application.app`. And I think you might need to have an `__init__.py` in  `my_project` folder.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. However, adding __init__.py to the project directory and importing my_project.application.app in `unit_test.py` gives the exact same error.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that import statements are relative to the directory you are currently in. The solution to calling another script in the same directory is to use relative imports. In this case, `from .utils import func1, func2, func3` worked!